# Is mixing software RAID disks across SATA and eSATA going to have any issues?

Tags: centos, raid, sata, software-raid, esata

I have two eSATA drives running successfully in a software RAID on CentOS. I would like to make this a three disk mirror RAID by adding the third drive from the internal SATA drive. Are there any issues or performance concerns in running a RAID in this type of configuration?

My understanding is eSATA is just an external SATA, but I thought I would ask to see if there are any issues I'm not considering before I configure the system this way.

Comment: There shouldn't be.  The best way to find out if this will be supported is to simply try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is eSATA is just an external SATA,

Precisely.  There are differences, such as a different connector and higher voltage on the cables. But it should just work.

The only exiting thing will be if you accidentally cut power to the external drive, causing the array to fall to a degraded state.